# How fix 'type=value_error' when loading a wizard-vicuna model to PrivateGPT?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface, large-language-model, llamacpp

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3F5riM5BNE) to install [PrivateGPT](https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT) and be able to query with a LLM about my local documents.
I'm using a `wizard-vicuna-13B.ggmlv3.q4_1.bin` [model](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/wizard-vicuna-13B-GGML/tree/main), and as per the README.md adjusted the example.env file settings to a new .env file:
from

```
PERSIST_DIRECTORY=db
MODEL_TYPE=GPT4All
MODEL_PATH=models/ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin
EMBEDDINGS_MODEL_NAME=all-MiniLM-L6-v2
MODEL_N_CTX=1000
MODEL_N_BATCH=8
TARGET_SOURCE_CHUNKS=4
```

to

```
PERSIST_DIRECTORY=db
MODEL_TYPE=LlamaCpp
MODEL_PATH=models/wizard-vicuna-13B.ggmlv3.q4_1.bin
EMBEDDINGS_MODEL_NAME=all-MiniLM-L6-v2
MODEL_N_CTX=1000
MODEL_N_BATCH=8
TARGET_SOURCE_CHUNKS=4
```

I haven't changed any other code and successfully ran the `ingest.py` command that processes the given source documents, yet I receive the following error when trying to run the program with `python3 privateGPT.py`:

```
Using embedded DuckDB with persistence: data will be stored in: db
llama.cpp: loading model from models/wizard-vicuna-13B.ggmlv3.q4_1.bin
error loading model: unknown (magic, version) combination: 73726576, 206e6f69; is this really a GGML file?
llama_init_from_file: failed to load model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/aiExplore/privateGPT23.7.11/privateGPT/privateGPT.py", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/aiExplore/privateGPT23.7.11/privateGPT/privateGPT.py", line 36, in main
    llm = LlamaCpp(model_path=model_path, n_ctx=model_n_ctx, n_batch=model_n_batch, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=False)
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for LlamaCpp
__root__
  Could not load Llama model from path: models/wizard-vicuna-13B.ggmlv3.q4_1.bin. Received error  (type=value_error)
```

In a [HF thread](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/gpt4-alpaca-lora_mlp-65B-GGML/discussions/4) with the same error, TheBloke advised to

> update llama.cpp, or whatever UI/code you're using

Is this error related to updating llama.cpp? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Have you verified that the downloaded model was present inside the model directory?